# VB6: Object Variable or With Block Variable Not Set

Tags: vb6

Current high school student learning vb6 and having this major problem when trying to set the left and top values of these image boxes. I keep getting the error:

> Object Variable or With Block Variable Not Set

and debug seems to lead it to the left and top value variables.

```
Option Explicit

Dim GapY As Integer
Dim GapX As Integer

Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer

Dim Tile() As Image
Dim NumOfTiles

Dim h, i As Integer 'Counter       

Private Sub cmdRender_Click()
    x = 480
    y = 480

    GapX = Val(InputBox("Enter How Many tile you want horizontally:"))
    GapY = Val(InputBox("Enter How Many tile you want vertically"))

    NumOfTiles = (GapY * GapX)

    ReDim Tile(NumOfTiles)

    For i = 1 To GapY
        For h = 1 To GapX

           Tile(h).Height = 615
           Tile(h).Width = 615
           Tile(h).Left = x
           Tile(h).Top = y         
           'Tile(h).Stretch = True
           x = x + 600
        Next
        y = y + 600
        x = 480
    Next                
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not assigned any image to your tile array, i.e. you have an array with `NumOfTiles` empty positions.

I don't know where you are getting your images from. You might create images with `new Image` or read images from files or take them from image boxes on a form etc.

---

Probably you want to work with `PictureBox` controls. if you have such controls on a form, you would have to type the array as such

```
Dim Tile() As PictureBox
ReDim Tile(NumOfTiles) As PictureBox
```

And then assign them from your form (assuming that you have placed some on a form):

```
Set Tile(1) = pictureBox1
Set Tile(2) = pictureBox2
...
```

or in a loop

```
For i = 1 To NumOfTiles
    Set Tile(i) = Me("pictureBox" & i)
    Tile(i).Left = ...
Next
```

or create them on the form with something like this (I did not try it out)

```
Set Tile(i) = Me.Controls.Add("VB.PictureBox", "pictureBox" & i)
```

Comment: I want the imageboxes to stay empty for now, but this isn't where my problem derives from. It's the moment i try to change one of the image boxes propertys such as .left and .top.

Comment: `Tile(i)` is `Nothing`, i.e. the picture boxes are not empty, they are not existing at all!

Comment: Olivier is right.  You've created an array to hold Images but no actual images.  It's like you've created a load of shoe boxes with no shoes in them.  You can put a shoe into the box but you can't do anything with a shoe until you put one in the box.  So you're saying the equivalent of 'Tie up the laces of the shoe in box 1' when there isn't a shoe in there.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, this really helped.